# PHP file upload not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload files to my server but it doesn't work at all. Here is test code:

```
<?php
echo count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="upload[]" type="file" accept=".mp3" multiple="multiple" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**It always prints 0**, file upload is enabled on my server.

Comment: <input name="upload" type="file" accept=".mp3" multiple="multiple" /> remove [] OR var_dump($_FILES['upload']) for multiple files

Comment: if you make `echo count($_FILES['upload'])` you'll obtain the correct result. It will be an array of elements with only one element. As @Jeremy suggest, remove the array `[]` notation to avoid send array instead of propper file (at least if you don't have to send multiple files at once)

Comment: This should be closed as offtopic > typographycal error.

Comment: It's still not working even with `name="upload"`

Comment: I just tested the code on my live server and it works, time to reinstall wamp....

Comment: not working because you use count. Use var_dump to see the $_FILES structure, and if you don't understand, ask your questions, but not like this. don't need reinstall

Comment: Why count wouldn't work with array?

Comment: If you want to count you should remove name and have something like this: `echo count($_FILES['upload']);` But make sure you have correct value in `$_FILES['upload']`, not only count.

Comment: because $_FILES['upload']['name'] is not an array. The structure of $_FILES['upload'] is different if multiple is activated. Once again, try var_dump($_FILES['upload']); and see the result.

Comment: Also var_dump returns this: `array (size=1)
  0 => string '' (length=0)`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: if(array_key_exists('upload', $_FILES)) { var_dump($_FILES['upload']); } else { echo "Please upload a file."; }

Comment: This is really weird. Running code above always return "Please upload a file"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not counting the `$_FILES['upload']`.

**Simple fix for your problem**
Use:

```
echo count($_FILES['upload']);
```

Instead of:

```
echo count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
```

**Edit:** 
Remove `[]` from the input's name.

Comment: Still not working, I think the code isn't the problem since it works on live server.

Comment: @user47823 I fixed one thing in the code. Try reinstalling your apache server's software (eg. Wamp), then look for the Apache config if it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
  echo count($_FILES['upload']);//only this modified//
  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
       <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="upload[]" type="file" accept=".mp3" multiple="multiple" />
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```